# npm error when moving project from android to iOS?

Tags: react-native-ios

I am moving my React Native proj to MacOS for IOS from Windows Android. The project is initiated by:

```
npx react-native init myproj
```

Then test with:

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

it worked with simulator. Then I copy the `package.json, App.js` and components to the `myproj` and run `yarn install`. But now `run-ios` throws out error about `npm`:

```
npx react-narive run-ios
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/react-narive - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'react-narive@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Tried `npx set config registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` and it didn't help.

Since I am not using `npm` for module installation, what caused the error and how to fix?

Comment: have you tried first cd ios then pod install ?

Comment: did and `pod install` had error about `command config` not recognized and `Invalid Podfile`.

Comment: gem `cocoapod` was installed successfully.

Comment: Here is a post about the issue but didn't provide solution. https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/846

Answer (score 0):

Just update the react native cli module to latest from `@react-native-community/cli` by:

```
yarn add @react-native-community/cli
```

and run `pod install` under `/ios`.

The current version the community cli is `3.0.4`. The previous version of cli installed was `2.0.1` from `react-native-cli` which was obsolete.